# How to configure XWayland to accept remote X client connections in Debian 12?

Tags: linux, debian, wayland

Title basically says it all.  I know I can revert back to x.org, but since Wayland is now the default I want to stick with it and get used to using Wayland moving forward.

However, I'm having a heck of time figuring out how to get XWayland to accept remote X client connections.  I figure I'd need to somehow pass the "-listen tcp" command line option to XWayland.  Can somebody give me a hint?  This is on Debian 12, btw.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for _programming_ questions. You might want to explore our sibling site [unix.se], but please read their help pages before asking there (and please delete this off-topic post, and review our [help] before posting here again).